# One liner to run a ForkJoinTask on another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am testing some concurrent behaviour and need to fire off a lot of calls to run on another thread.

I was previous using `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` for this, but I have noticed it sometimes run the task on the same thread (due to work-stealing?)!

So I will now need something that uses real threads and returns `ForkJoinTask`s. Preferably, each call can be a one-liner.

I have looked at submitting a job to an Executor, but I would rather have something like `commonPool` which does not require setup or pull down.

Update:

I think I can do `(new Thread(ForkJoinTask.adapt(...)).start()`, but this feels rather hacky....

Comment: Pretty sure you need an actual Executor and to accept that setup and pull down will be necessary.

Comment: if you are sensible to the fact that a task runs on the same thread, then probably your desing is flawed.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Normally I would agree with you, but this is specifically to test some `ThreadLocal` code is correct.

Comment: to run in another thread, submit your task to another thread pool. You can start many different thread pools simultaneously.